# Verifying pdf document signature using PHP's openssl

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature

So I have this code for a simple test.

```
<?php

while(openssl_error_string() !== false);

$input_filename = 'tmp/file.pdf';
$output_filename = 'tmp/file-signed.pdf';

$certificate = 'C:\\path_on_my_pc\\certificate.pem';
$private_key = 'C:\\path_on_my_pc\\private_key.pem';

$res = openssl_pkcs7_sign(
    $input_filename, 
    $output_filename, 
    'file://'.$certificate, 
    'file://'.$private_key, 
    [], 
    PKCS7_BINARY|PKCS7_DETACHED);
echo 'sign='.var_export($res, true).PHP_EOL;

$res = openssl_pkcs7_verify($output_filename, PKCS7_NOVERIFY);
echo 'verify='.var_export($res, true).PHP_EOL;


do {
    $erro = openssl_error_string();
    echo 'err='.var_export($erro,true).PHP_EOL;
} while($erro !== false);
```

I'm having trouble in the signature verify step. 
When using with a text file (and without PKCS7_BINARY) it works fine, but using with a pdf file I got the result "**verify=-1**" and the error:

> error:068000D2:asn1 encoding routines::no multipart body failure

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

I'm using wampserver for windows with php 8.2.0.